# jQuery LayoutCreator Plugin, 2-column layout error

Tags: jquery, layout, plugins

I am trying to implement the plugin from the site http://ajaxtown.com but i am getting errors while using it in making a 2 column layout in "px". Can you please help me.

```
$("#container").layout({            
            cols: 2,
            layoutWidth:80px,
            left_col: {'display':true,'width':200,'id':'left_col','_class':'left_col','path':'contents/left.php'},      
            content_col: {'width':800,'id':'content_col','_class':'content_col','path':'contents/center.html'},     
            header: {'display':true,'id':'header','_class':'','height':'auto','path':'contents/header.html','load_once':true},
            footer: {'display':true,'id':'footer','_class':'','height':'auto','path':'contents/footer.html','load_once':true},      
            menu: {'display':true,'id':'menu','_class':'','height':'auto','path':'contents/menu.html','load_once':true},        
            colsPadding: 2,
            loadAtOnce: true,
            smartCSS: true,
            unit: 'px',
            preloadImage: 'ajax-loader.gif',
            paddOthers: false

        });
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an error in the JS:

```
layoutWidth:80px,
```

should be either

```
layoutWidth:"80px",
```

or

```
layoutWidth:80,
```

Im guessing the last one, since you define its pixels in the "unit" setting :)